# Type 'Observable<Observable<Login>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, effects

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjPpJ.png)

trying to solve this error any hint ?
this is the code trying to do post request then call an actions with resolved data

```js
export class AuthEffects {
authLoging= createEffect(
    ()=> this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(authActions.LOGIN_START),
        switchMap((authData:authActions.LoginStart)=>
               this.http.post<authResponse>('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=' + environment.FireBasekey,
                {
                    email: authData.payload?.email,
                    password: authData.payload?.password,
                    returnSecureToken: true
                }).pipe(map(resData => {
                    return of(new authActions.Login({
                        email: resData.email,
                        userId: resData.localId,
                        token: resData.idToken,
                        expirationDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + +resData.expiresIn * 1000)
                    }))
                })
                )
        )
                
    )
);

constructor(private actions$: Actions , private http:HttpClient){}
```

}

> Type 'Observable<Observable>' is not assignable to type 'EffectResult'.
> Type 'Observable<Observable>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
> Property 'type' is missing in type 'Observable' but required in type 'Action'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the of() in your map():

```
}).pipe(map(resData => {
                    return new authActions.Login({
```

The map Operator wraps it in an observable already.

You also have to return an action in your effect.

Another Tip: Add a `catchError` in the same pipe, otherwise your effect will terminate if the HttpCall fails once.

Answer (score 0):

it works when I remove of operator from here an return a new instance immediately

```
 return of(new authActions.Login({
                    email: resData.email,
                    userId: resData.localId,
                    token: resData.idToken,
                    expirationDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + +resData.expiresIn * 1000)
                }))
```